# Opensearch assumes wrong time zone

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

## Edit

Opensearch increases the timestamp of the logs by one hour. It must somehow assume that the logs come from the UTC time zone. How do I change this behaviour?

`2023-02-02 12:47:27,897 [INFO]: <log>` becomes `2023-02-02 13:47:27,897 [INFO]: <log>`

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation:

> Internally, dates are converted to UTC (if the time-zone is specified)
> and stored as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.
> Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

You can't change this behavior, but when you search the data you will see the correct time according to your browser time. Or you can specify the time zone during the search. For example:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2023-02-02 12:47:27",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
        "time_zone": "+01:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```